# Stressing innovative studies has or have had?

Tags: grammatical-number, past-tense, gerunds

I am unsure whether the sentence would make grammatical sense as has or have had. Is this sentence fragment considered singular or plural? Is stressing a gerund that makes it singular? Because innovative studies is plural, so I assumed that this sentence was plural and I needed the use of have had.

Comment: What sentence??

Answer (score 1):

The verb agrees with the singular gerund, *stressing*. So, *has*. *Innovative studies* is an object (*studies*) of the gerund that serves as the subject here, with a modifying adjective (*innovative*). It's irrelevant.